# Как можно в методе IndexOfAny сделать игнорирование регистра?

Tags: c#, строки

Да, можно для этого использовать метод просто IndexOf, который принимает StringComparison, можно сделать игнорирование регистра.
Но  как именно сделать в методе IndexOfAny?

```
string str = "GuB"; 
char[]mass = {'U'}; 
int index = str.IndexOfAny(mass,0,mass.Length) ; 
Console.WriteLine(index);
```

Перегрузок у данного метода для игнорирование регистра нет, информации на просторах интернета нету. Как вообще при переборе массива (сравнении) игнорировать регистр? Прямо в методе IndexOfAny

Comment: Привести строку и искомый символ/массив символов к единому регистру при помощи `ToLower` или `ToUpper`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если в исходной строке и/или массиве искомых символов допускаются символы разных регистров, то следует привести к какому-то одному регистру.

Также следует учесть, что метод [String.IndexOfAny(char[] arr, int start, int count)](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.string.indexofany?view=net-7.0#system-string-indexofany(system-char()-system-int32-system-int32)) будет проверять `count` символов в заданной строке, то есть если передать туда размер массива из одного элемента, то ничего не найдется.

*Дополнение:* При преобразовании в верхний регистр в *общем случае* (когда могут использоваться некоторые экзотические алфавиты и символы) нужно устанавливать [`CultureInfo.InvariantCulture`](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.globalization.cultureinfo.invariantculture?view=net-8.0) либо в текущем потоке выполнения, либо в каждом преобразовании регистра.

Пример 1.
В верхний регистр переводится только строка, в массиве заведомо только прописные буквы:

```cs
// для корректной обработки символов некоторых экзотических алфавитов
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;

string str = "GuB";
string ups = str.ToUpper(); 
char[] mass = {'U'}; 
int index = ups.IndexOfAny(mass); 
Console.WriteLine(index); // 1

index = ups.IndexOfAny(mass, 0); 
Console.WriteLine(index); // 1

index = ups.IndexOfAny(mass, 0, mass.Length); // длина массива 1, проверить только 1 символ 
Console.WriteLine(index); // -1

index = ups.IndexOfAny(mass, 0, str.Length); // проверить всю строку 
Console.WriteLine(index); // 1
```

Пример 2.
В верхний регистр переводятся и строка и массив:

```cs
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;

string str = "ıGuB";  // турецкая ı без точки
string ups = str.ToUpper(); 
char[] mass = {'U', 'g', 'ı'};
char[] arr = new string(mass).ToUpper().ToCharArray();
int index = ups.IndexOfAny(arr); 
Console.WriteLine(index); // 0 -- первым найден символ 'ı'
```

Comment: Скажите пж у меня - 1 выводит, я хотел без доп строковой переменной, прямо в выражении все сделать.Ошибку исправил связанную с длиной поиска. string str = "GuB";
   char[]mass = {'U'};
   int index = str.ToUpper().IndexOfAny(mass.ToString().ToUpper().ToCharArray(),0,str.Length);
   Console.WriteLine(index);

Comment: `mass.ToString()` вернёт строку `"System.Char[]"`, а не ожидаемую `"U"`, нужно использовать [конструктор](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.string.-ctor?view=net-7.0#system-string-ctor(system-char())).  Если поиск нужен по всей строке, проще использовать вариант метода `IndexOfAny` с меньшим числом параметров.

Comment: спасибо, решил не переопределять ToString, создал просто анонимный объект string и инициализ его массивом. IndexOfAny(new String(mass).ToUpper().ToCharArray())

Comment: Ваша идея не вполне верна, вот контрпример: https://sharplab.io/#v2:C4LgTgrgdgNAJiA1AHwAICYCMBYAUKgBgAJVMA6AcQBsB7AIwEMqBLALweGZqgG49CS5ACoALMAFMGcZlADmfXHlESpZAMIQwEqMGWS46zduAaqwTeKIBeIlHEB3IqfMSAklABmNABQAicVAAtACqAMq+AJQK/JjEIgwAngDOwAwAxgDW1kS+zL4KafFgtuLicFSWNgDkgIyAVTxEAPSNRHA0wBVJSUTMMXGJKekZwQAOI+LFNvHJqZlkQjSj42DeUXiFDGAA2gC6JWUVSxPZdva7RADeRBtg84tjE952B+IRRAC+0bgywD1QcOIAB7ZaaDTJHW7uAGAgDyHgAglAEk9SuVxBC1vhMABObwyaGYoA===. То, что апкейснутые символы совпадают, вовсе не гарантирует, что первоначальные символы совпадают или отличаются лишь регистром.

Comment: @VladD вы имеете ввиду региональные настройки? То что один символ из другого алфавита принимается за один и тот-же из другого?

Comment: @Hlebushek: Я имею в виду, что upcase от двух разных символов может быть одним и тем же символом. Например, `char.ToUpper('i')` = `char.ToUpper('ı')` = `'I'`. Это так и в английской, и в русской региональной настройке (но не в турецкой, например).

Comment: Поэтому при переводе в верхний регистр теряется отличие i от ı.

Comment: string haystack = "i";
char needle = 'ı'; // dotless i
string haystackUpper = haystack.ToUpper();
char[] needleUpper = new[] { char.ToUpper(needle,CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) };

int index = haystackUpper.IndexOfAny(needleUpper);
Console.WriteLine(index);Додумался вроде

Comment: @VladD, дополнил ответ

Comment: @NowhereMan: Вы не можете так просто перейти к инвариантной культуре, т. к. при этом перевод в заглавные буквы будет неверен. Например, [в Турции ожидают](https://sharplab.io/#v2:C4LgTgrgdgNAJiA1AHwAIAYAEqCMA6AcQBsB7AIwEMiBLALwuGpKgG4BYAKA23wBUALMAFMKcalADm7LllwA2HngDCzAM4kiQ6ZwHDRyiGGFRgukXANGhJpRCLBDQzAF5Mt+44CSUAGYk83gBuFGDUFDZ2DsLSAOqhwEIAMuJCABQAxvwheLwkAKoADgVCYKkA5NRlAJRV0mb6tlYm9RaNxsDuUU6uUEIA7m6RXr4kqQBEwGAAtLwASmO1nHHUCcm9GVlgOflFJeWVNSxAA=), что прописной вариант `'i'` будет `'İ'`, а не `'I'`.

Comment: То, какая заглавная буква соответствует какой строчной (точнее: какая или какие заглавные соответствуют какой или каким строчным), зависит от языка, так что и ответ должен зависеть от языка.

Comment: @VladD Где в исходном вопросе указывалось требование о турецкой культуре или о проблемах с ней? :)

Comment: @NowhereMan Нигде. Но код ведь должен работать в любой стране, верно?